# How to perform cross-validation with LightGBM.LGBMRanker, while keeping groups together?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, ranking, lightgbm

I'm on a search problem, I have a dataset of queries and urls. Each couple (query, url) has a relevance (the target), a float which should preserve the order of the urls, for a given query.
I would like to perform cross validation for my lightgbm.LGBMRanker model, with the objective as ndcg.

I went through the documentation and saw that it is important to keep the instances in the same `group`, because an instance is actually a query with all its associated urls.
I however have an issue regarding this, as I get the following error :

```bash
ValueError: Computing NDCG is only meaningful when there is more than 1 document. Got 1 instead.
```

I used the debugger, and while I do not have any group which size is inferior to `2` in my dataset, I have groups which are smaller in the `_feval` function, meaning the `cv()` fucntion did not actually keep the groups together.

In the [lightgbm.cv](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/pythonapi/lightgbm.cv.html) I see no sign of the `group` argument which is used in the [LGBMRanker](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRanker.html).
But I can see that the function lightbm.cv precises that `Values passed through params take precedence over those supplied via arguments`. My understanding was that this value is passed to the underlying model of the cv function.

Here is the code that I have so far :

```
def eval_model(
    self,
    model: lightgbm.LGBMRanker,
    k_fold: int = 3,
    seed: int = 42,
):
    """Evaluates with NDCG"""

    def _feval(y_pred: np.ndarray, lgb_dataset: lightgbm.basic.Dataset):
        y_true = lgb_dataset.get_label()
        serp_sizes = lgb_dataset.get_group()

        ndcg_values = []
        start = 0
        for size in serp_sizes:
            end = start + size
            y_true_serp, y_pred_serp = y_true[start:end], y_pred[start:end]
            ndcg_serp = sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score(
                [y_true_serp], [y_pred_serp], k=10
            )
            ndcg_values.append(ndcg_serp)
            start = end

        eval_name = "my-ndcg"
        eval_result = np.mean(ndcg_values)
        greater_is_better = True
        return eval_name, eval_result, greater_is_better

    lgb_dataset = lightgbm.Dataset(data=self.X, label=self.y, group=self.serp_sizes)
    cv_results = lightgbm.cv(
        params={**model.get_params(), "group": self.serp_sizes},
        train_set=lgb_dataset,
        num_boost_round=1_000,
        nfold=k_fold,
        stratified=False,
        seed=seed,
        feval=_feval,
    )
    ndcg = np.mean(cv_results["my-ndcg"])

    return ndcg
```

Where is my mistake/misunderstanding ?
is there a simple workaround to perform cross-validation using a `lightgbm.LGBMRanker`, and keeping the groups together ?

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would like to perform cross validation for my lightgbm.LGBMRanker model, with the objective as ndcg.*

As of `lightgbm==4.1.0` (the latest version as of this writing), `lightgbm.sklearn.LGBMRanker` cannot be used with `scikit-learn`'s cross-validation APIs.

It also cannot be passed to `lightgbm.cv()`.

> *In the lightgbm.cv I see no sign of the group argument which is used in the LGBMRanker*

As described in LightGBM's documentation ([link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/pythonapi/lightgbm.cv.html#lightgbm.cv)), `lightgbm.cv()` expects to be passed a `lightgbm.Dataset` object.

`group` is an attribute of the `Dataset` object.

To perform cross-validation of a LightGBM learning-to-rank model, use `lightgbm.cv()` instead of `lightgbm.sklearn.LGBMRanker()`.

Here's a minimal, reproducible example using 3.11.7 and `lightgbm==4.1.0`.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np
import requests
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

# get training data from LightGBM examples
data_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/LightGBM/master/examples/lambdarank"
with NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w") as f:
    train_data_raw = requests.get(f"{data_url}/rank.train").text
    f.write(train_data_raw)
    X, y = load_svmlight_file(f.name)

group = np.loadtxt(f"{data_url}/rank.train.query")

# create a LightGBM Dataset
dtrain = lgb.Dataset(
    data=X,
    label=y,
    group=group
)

# perform LambdaRank 3-fold cross-validation with 1 set of hyperparameters
cv_results = lgb.cv(
    train_set=dtrain,
    params={
        "objective": "lambdarank",
        "eval_at": 2,
        "num_iterations": 10
    },
    nfold=3,
    return_cvbooster=True
)

# check metrics
np.round(cv_results["valid ndcg@2-mean"], 3)
# array([0.593, 0.597, 0.64 , 0.632, 0.64 , 0.636, 0.655, 0.655, 0.653, 0.669])
```

`lightgbm.cv()` will correctly preserve query groups when creating cross-validation folds.

> *Values passed through params take precedence over those supplied via arguments*

In LightGBM's documentation, "param" refers specifically to the configuration described at https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/Parameters.html.

The statement you've quoted does not apply to data like `group`, `init_score`, and `label`, and those things should not be passed through the `params` keyword argument in any of LightGBM's interfaces.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reproducible example !
It finallay helped me make it work :)